# Flagging questions

Tags: support, flagging

I feel I need to flag two questions ([1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7710/how-to-consider-krishna-a-good-or-bad), [2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7711/why-yudhisthira-went-to-hell)) because they are unclear and are quite related to each other, but both happen to be from the same user. Should I go ahead and flag them or would the user feel targeted?

Comment: Feel free to flag any and all content.  Flags are only visible to moderators.

Comment: As Keshav said above, flags are carried away anonymously. Just flag it if you think to do.